# Alternative for display:contents in Chrome?

Tags: css, google-chrome

What is the alternate solution to implement the following in chrome.

```
display:contents;
```

Currently only firefox supports them in all versions.

Is there any other way to get the same features as this css tag.

[image]

Comment: Caniuse is out of date, it's said to be enabled in Chrome 65. https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5663606012116992 https://crbug.com/657748 https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/d/topic/blink-dev/XzdNrEvn4Qk

Comment: But thats possible when we enable it right?

Comment: https://codepen.io/paulobrien/pen/jYYKmB appears to be doing it in browser without support for it. Tested in Chrome and works. Resize browser window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an alternative approach, instead using display:content (that is marked as experimental at the moment) you can create a container class and add the property `display:grid`, and, in case the browser supports `display:content` use it with this code:

```
@supports (display: contents) {
  article { display: contents; }
}
```

Comment: Can you flesh this out with a fuller example, including the container?

Answer (score 1):

```
.display-contents {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```