# Nested CSS flexbox problem - only with Safari 14 / MacOS browser

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have prepared a simple test case (below), which uses a nested CSS flexbox to give max possible space to the checkered `#pixiCanvas`, while keeping the yellow `#hintDiv` and `#totalDiv` at the screen top/bottom:

[image: Firefox]

The problem is that while my code works perfectly on other browsers (Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Edge, even IE 11; after I have followed the advice to add `min-width`, `min-height` to `#mainDiv` and its children) it **does not work with Safari 14 / MacOS** -

The `#mainDiv` or maybe `#gameDiv` grow too tall and push `#totalDiv` out of the screen, while `#pixiCanvas` is cut off and not displayed entirely:

[image: Safari 14]

The structure of my web page is:

```
- fullDiv (should occupy 100% / 100 vh)
-- leftDiv
-- mainDiv
--- hintDiv (100% width, on top of screen)
--- gameDiv (should have max possible width and height)
--- totalDiv (100% width, on bottom of screen)
-- rightDiv
```

Here is my code (open in Safari to see the issue):

```js
  $(function() {
    $(':button').button();
    $('#fullCheck').checkboxradio();

    var gamesMenu = $('#gamesMenu').menu({
      items: '> :not(.ui-widget-header)',
      select: function(ev, ui) {
        ui.item.addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected');
      }
    });

    for (var game = 1; game <= 50; game++) {
      gamesMenu.append('<LI CLASS="ui-menu-item-wrapper" VALUE="' + game + '">GAME ' + game + '</LI>');
    }

    gamesMenu.menu('refresh');

    var WIDTH = 400;
    var HEIGHT = 400;

    var app = new PIXI.Application({
      width: WIDTH,
      height: HEIGHT,
      view: document.getElementById('pixiCanvas'),
      backgroundColor: 0xFFFFFF
    });

    var background = new PIXI.Graphics();
    for (var i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
      for (var j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
        if ((i + j) % 2 == 0) {
          background.beginFill(0xCCCCFF);
          background.drawRect(i * WIDTH / 8, j * HEIGHT / 8, WIDTH / 8, HEIGHT / 8);
          background.endFill();
        }
      }
    }
    app.stage.addChild(background);
  });
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#fullDiv {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background: #FFF;
  display: flex;
}

#hintDiv,
#totalDiv {
  font-style: italic;
  text-align: center;
  background: yellow;
}

#leftDiv {
  text-align: center;
  background: #FCC;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#gamesMenu {
  overflow: auto;
}

#mainDiv {
  flex-grow: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  min-width: 200px;
  min-height: 200px;
  
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px green dashed;
}

#gameDiv {
  flex-grow: 1;
  min-width: 150px;
  min-height: 150px;
}

#pixiCanvas {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  min-width: 100px;
  min-height: 100px;
  background: #CCF;

  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 4px red dotted;
}

#rightDiv {
  text-align: center;
  background: #CFC;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

li.selected {
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div id="fullDiv">
  <div id="leftDiv">
    <button id="newBtn">New game</button>
    <ul id="gamesMenu"></ul>
  </div>

  <div id="mainDiv">
    <div id="hintDiv">Hint</div>

    <div id="gameDiv">
      <canvas id="pixiCanvas"></canvas>
    </div>

    <div id="totalDiv">Total score</div>
  </div>

  <div id="rightDiv">
    <input id="fullCheck" type="checkbox">
    <label for="fullCheck">Full screen</label><br>
    <button id="recallBtn">Recall</button><br>
    <button id="shuffleBtn">Shuffle</button><br>
    <button id="swapBtn">Swap</button><br>
    <button id="skipBtn">Skip</button><br>
    <button id="resignBtn">Resign</button><br>
    <button id="pileBtn">Pile</button><br>
    <button id="movesBtn">Moves history</button><br>
    <button id="shareBtn">Share</button><br>
    <button id="playBtn">Play</button>
  </div>
</div>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css">
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/pixi.js@5.3.3/dist/pixi.min.js"></script>
```

Here the screenshot of [my word game](https://wordsbyfarber.com), where the `#pixiCanvas` grows too large and is shown underneath the grey chat area at the bottom:

[image: Safari]

The only workaround I have been able to come up sofar has been:

```
if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Safari') >= 0) {
    $('#gameDiv').css('overflow', 'auto');
}
```

but it makes the usage of my word game awkward while dragging letters.

P.S. I would prefer not to switch to CSS grid, because I have an impression that CSS flex is better supported (and some of my users still use IE 11).

Comment: And if you add CSS property: `#totalDiv{bottom:0}` or `{ margin-bottom: auto; }`, does it change something ?

Comment: min-height:0 on gamediv

Comment: Adding `min-width` and `min-height` to all children has helped, thank you! Only Safari on MacOS is still broken. I have updated my question and the title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply add `display: contents;` to `#gameDiv`:

```
#gameDiv{
  display: contents;
}
```

Browser compatibility for [display contents](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display#Browser_compatibility)

As you can see this display is not compatible with IE. But this is fine because IE will ignore it and apply default `display: block` that works fine in IE (I tested it).

Any if you want it to be sure to apply the right display, you can still keep `display: block` by using 2 display as in this [subject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48535296/alternative-for-displaycontents-in-chrome).

Using:

```
@supports (display: contents) {
  #gameDiv { display: contents; }
}
```

Demo:

```js
$(function() {
    $(':button').button();
    $('#fullCheck').checkboxradio();

    var gamesMenu = $('#gamesMenu').menu({
      items: '> :not(.ui-widget-header)',
      select: function(ev, ui) {
        ui.item.addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected');
      }
    });

    for (var game = 1; game <= 50; game++) {
      gamesMenu.append('<LI CLASS="ui-menu-item-wrapper" VALUE="' + game + '">GAME ' + game + '</LI>');
    }

    gamesMenu.menu('refresh');

    var WIDTH = 400;
    var HEIGHT = 400;

    var app = new PIXI.Application({
      width: WIDTH,
      height: HEIGHT,
      view: document.getElementById('pixiCanvas'),
      backgroundColor: 0xFFFFFF
    });

    var background = new PIXI.Graphics();
    for (var i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
      for (var j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
        if ((i + j) % 2 == 0) {
          background.beginFill(0xCCCCFF);
          background.drawRect(i * WIDTH / 8, j * HEIGHT / 8, WIDTH / 8, HEIGHT / 8);
          background.endFill();
        }
      }
    }
    app.stage.addChild(background);
  });
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#fullDiv {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background: #FFF;
  display: flex;
}

#hintDiv,
#totalDiv {
  font-style: italic;
  text-align: center;
  background: yellow;
}

#leftDiv {
  text-align: center;
  background: #FCC;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#gamesMenu {
  overflow: auto;
}

#mainDiv {
  flex-grow: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  min-width: 200px;
  min-height: 200px;
  
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px green dashed;
}

#gameDiv {
  flex-grow: 1;
  min-width: 150px;
  min-height: 150px;
}

#pixiCanvas {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  min-width: 100px;
  min-height: 100px;
  background: #CCF;

  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 4px red dotted;
}

#rightDiv {
  text-align: center;
  background: #CFC;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

li.selected {
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: yellow;
}

#gameDiv{
  display: contents;
}
```

```html
<div id="fullDiv">
  <div id="leftDiv">
    <button id="newBtn">New game</button>
    <ul id="gamesMenu"></ul>
  </div>

  <div id="mainDiv">
    <div id="hintDiv">Hint</div>

    <div id="gameDiv">
      <canvas id="pixiCanvas"></canvas>
    </div>

    <div id="totalDiv">Total score</div>
  </div>

  <div id="rightDiv">
    <input id="fullCheck" type="checkbox">
    <label for="fullCheck">Full screen</label><br>
    <button id="recallBtn">Recall</button><br>
    <button id="shuffleBtn">Shuffle</button><br>
    <button id="swapBtn">Swap</button><br>
    <button id="skipBtn">Skip</button><br>
    <button id="resignBtn">Resign</button><br>
    <button id="pileBtn">Pile</button><br>
    <button id="movesBtn">Moves history</button><br>
    <button id="shareBtn">Share</button><br>
    <button id="playBtn">Play</button>
  </div>
</div>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css">
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/pixi.js@5.3.3/dist/pixi.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Such a simple fix, thank you! I don't understand though how it really works, does it make `#gameDiv` disappear and the CSS flexbox is applied to `#pixiCanvas`?

Comment: Glad that I solved your problem. More or less it does not create a box [specifications](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-display-3/#box-generation) or [CSS Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/get-ready-for-display-contents/)